# how can I introduce SqlLogger on my project with jdbi?

Tags: java, jdbi

Im using jdbi v3 and I recently wanted to add a logger to check my query statements.

Checking the documentation I found this https://jdbi.org/#_sqllogger

Which refers to this class https://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/Slf4JSqlLogger.html

Unfortunately, I found no records, dependencies, or any information about this class, seems like no longer exist? is it a new dependency that maybe was removed? or should I do something special to include it? Any idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version of the Jdbi 3 core JAR (currently that is v3.28.0).

As a Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbi3-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.28.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I believe the class was first introduced in v3.19.0.

---

As an alternative, if you don't want (or are unable) to upgrade, you can create your own class from the `org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.SqlLogger` interface.

Something like:

```java
public class MyLogger implements SqlLogger {

    @Override
    public void logAfterExecution(StatementContext ctx) {
        ...
        ctx.getParsedSql()...;
    }

}
```